# How to find symmetric mean absolute error in python?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

How can I calculate symmetric mean absolute error in python using numpy or pandas? Is there are metric present in scikit sklearn ?

Example data:

```
Actual value:   2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
Forecast value: 1,3,5,4,6,7,10,7
```

Formula for SMAPE see screenshot below:

[image]

How can I do it in python using pandas or numpy and calculate SMAPE.

Note: More info about SMAPE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error

Comment: To my knowledge, this metric is not available in common libraries. Simply implement it yourself...the formulae is straightforward.

Comment: @Kefeng91 I am not able to understand how ? How to get `100%/n`. If possible can you please write answer ?

Comment: The 100% just means that the metric is expressed as a percentage. Without it, the result would lie between 0 and 1. Thus, you just need to multiply by 100.

Comment: @Kefeng91 If possible can you please write an answer :)

Comment: `http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error.html`, this may help you.

Comment: I could, but rules of SO requires you to write it first. If your attempt does not work, you can paste your code so that we can help you. SO is not a "write my code for me" forum.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to convert the equation to numpy

```
import numpy as np

def smape(A, F):
    return 100/len(A) * np.sum(2 * np.abs(F - A) / (np.abs(A) + np.abs(F)))

A = np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
F = np.array([1,3,5,4,6,7,10,7])
print(smape(A, F))
```

Comment: great answer - just wondering is it `100/len(A)` or `1/len(A)` because it says `100%` in the function

Comment: @gyx-hh: depends on whether you want it as a percentage or not. Usually, in mathematics you don't put *100%*, you express percentages as values in [0, 1], but that's how the OP defined it

Comment: @blue_note Why `100/len(A)` it should be `100/n`

Comment: @stonerock: The `n` value is the number of values you have. So, either `len(A)` or `len(F)`. Just be sure they are equal

Comment: @blue_note Oh my god sorry my bad. I am such a noob

Comment: @stonerock: oversight, it happens (often)

Comment: for Python 2.7 you should change `100` to `100.` or `float(100)`.
Otherwise it will equal to zero for arrays longer than 100.

Comment: also in to avoid the possible `division by zero`
i would update `(np.abs(A) + np.abs(F))` to `(np.abs(A) + np.abs(F)) + np.finfo(float).eps`.
I just adds `epsilon` value for some kind of regularization.

Comment: @MichaelD: it is *supposed to be* undefined for 0/0. 0 error for 0 value is not 0 percent.

Comment: @blue_note, if `true value = 0` and `predicted value = 0`, the SMAPE should be equal to zero and not undefined. Do you agree with me?

Comment: @MichaelD: It could mean 100% success as well, so it should be 1. That's why it's undefined

Comment: @blue_note, i disagree, it means 100% success, so the error (SMAPE) should equals 0, not 1.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error

Comment: Maybe even better to deal with nans is to use np.nansum instead of np.sum.

Comment: Does this function work when with multiple-output linear regression? I'm trying to use this metric, but I'm getting a huge SMAPE despite having an r^2 of only 0.7.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
def mape(row):
    return abs(row.Forecast - row.Actual) / ((abs(row.Actual) + abs(row.Forecast))/2)

# create the pandas dataframe if you dont have one already
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Actual':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'Forecast':[1,3,5,4,6,7,10,7]})

# apply the above function on each row 
smape = df.apply(mape, axis=1).sum() * (1/len(df))
```

Output: `0.19791666666666669`

Comment: @blue_note's function is good. If you want to use pandas you can use his function by calling `smape(df.Actual, df.Forecast)`

Answer (score 1):

I commented on the accepted answer but if you just want to copy and paste:

```
import numpy as np

def smape(A, F):
    tmp = 2 * np.abs(F - A) / (np.abs(A) + np.abs(F))
    len_ = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(tmp))
    if len_ == 0 and np.nansum(tmp) == 0: # Deals with a special case
        return 100
    return 100 / len_ * np.nansum(tmp)

A = np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0])
F = np.array([1,3,5,4,6,7,10,0])
print(smape(A, F))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd prefer SMAPE = 0 when the actual and predicted values are both 0:

```
import numpy as np

def smape(A, F):
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        tmp = 2 * np.abs(F-A) / (np.abs(A) + np.abs(F))
    tmp[np.isnan(tmp)] = 0
    return np.sum(tmp) / len(tmp) * 100

A = np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7,0])
F = np.array([1,3,5,4,6,7,0])
print(smape(A, F))

>> 15.873015873015875
```